# Why is 'accept_mutex' 'on' as default in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, mutex

I found 'accept_mutex' is 'on' as default in Nginx as follows:

> http://wiki.nginx.org/EventsModule

Then does accepting connection require mutex? Why?

Comment: Yes. It uses mutex to serialize new connections. You can find some info here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#accept_mutex. However, I'd like to know more than that.

Comment: FYI: `accept_mutex` now defaults to `off`since Nginx 1.11.3 (https://nginx.org/en/CHANGES)

Comment: @ChuanMa Take a look at the doc in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

As of nginx mainline version 1.11.3 (released 2016-07-26), [`accept_mutex` now defaults to `off`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#accept_mutex). This is partly because the new `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` flag provides the benefits of `accept_mutex` without the extra overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine some processes listen on one port and wait in epoll.
Without accept mutex all processes will wake up, but only one will be able to accept connection. Others process waked up unproductive.
It is well known http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem

But it is not the end of story.

Often or always unsuccessful accept will result in context switch:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_convoy

My tests show 5-10% performance lost without accept mutex.

Update: "accept mutex" is not just mutext locked around accept.
It is the name of technology used to serialize listening on server port between workers.
Only one worker is listening for given port in one moment.

Comment: If accept mutex on is more efficient, why is there an option for off? When will it be useful?

Comment: As I know there were very seldom problems with accept mutex and others modules/configurations. Sometimes set accept_mutes off may help.

Comment: Turning `accept_mutex off;` can decrease latency by tens of milliseconds if number of qps is >>10k

Answer (score 1):

Check the

- *accept Serialization - Multiple Sockets*
- *accept Serialization - Single Socket*

sections of this Apache documentation. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html. (This doc matters most, compared to the rest of 2 I posted)

It's very inspiring and I also read the

http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#accept_mutex explaination as well as https://www.nginx.com/blog/performance-tuning-tips-tricks/ (search page with **accept_mutex**).

Aftering reading all of these, I guess Nginx is very similar to Apache in this aspect.